# I want to copy a zero width space to the clipboard

Tags: copy-paste

I want to copy a zero width space to the clipboard and paste it somewhere else, but after selecting all, the selecting handle thing doesn't pop up. I'm trying on chrome on [this site](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iLKwm).

Edit: no, I wouldn't want to do it with a character map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean here? Do you mean
- ONLY the zws
- zws WITH text

ONLY the zws? Go to [Emojipedia - Zero Width Joiner](https://emojipedia.org/zero-width-joiner/) (or click here). 
Then click on copy.

zws with text: *NO IDEA*